# How to calculate average grade

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm new to JavaScript and can't seem to figure out why my last function is not doing what it's suppose to do which is to use the average of entered grades(number) from the user to return a letter grade.

My first function is working how it should and my second function is written correctly (I think) but for my third function i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong because when I test run nothing shows up.

Here is what I've done within my code:

```js
var grades = [];
var totalSum = 0;


function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    grades[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Grade: "));
    document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML += grades[i] + "  ";
  }
}


function gradeAverage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    totalSum += grades[i];
    var average = totalSum / grades.length;
  }
}


function letterGrade() {

  if (totalSum <= 90) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " A";
  } else if (totalSum <= 80) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " B";
  } else if (totalSum <= 70) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " C";
  } else if (totalSum <= 60) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " D";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " F";
  }
}

myFunction();
gradeAverage();
letterGrade();
```

Comment: Read the console error; You need to return the average or it is not available outside the function. `var average = gradeAverage(); letterGrade(average)` OR move the declaration outside: `var average; gradeAverage(); letterGrade()` but that is not recommended.

Comment: Notice, that the logic doesn't do what you think it does. All the given values are below 90, and the grade is always set to `A`, no matter what is entered.

Comment: Dupe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316243/i-need-help-writing-an-if-else-statement-that-works

Answer (score 1):

You need average variable as global and some fix in your letterGrade() like this :

add: letterGrade() will always return A if score is 90 or below

```js
var grades = [];
var totalSum = 0;
var average = 0

// function to read five values from series of prompts stored in array
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    grades[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Grade: "));
    document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML += grades[i] + "  ";
  }
}

// function to calculate the average of the five entered grades and store it in a variable
function gradeAverage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    totalSum += grades[i];
    average = totalSum / grades.length;
  }
}

// funtion to use the average of entered grades to determine letter grade that it will return to the user
function letterGrade() {

  if (average >= 90 && average <= 100) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " A";
  } else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " B";
  } else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " C";
  } else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " D";
  } else if (average <= 59) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " F";
  }
}

myFunction();
gradeAverage();
letterGrade();
```

```html
<p id="gradeInput">You entered the following grades: </p>
<p id="finalGrade">Your grade average is: </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

- move the average var declaration outside the function (not really recommended, see later)
- reverse the ifs from <= to >=
- use average and not total sum in the ifs

```js
var grades = [];
var totalSum = 0;
var average =0;

// function to read five values from series of prompts stored in array
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    grades[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Grade: "));
    document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML += grades[i] + "  ";
  }
}

// function to calculate the average of the five entered grades and store it in a variable
function gradeAverage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    totalSum += grades[i];
    average = totalSum / grades.length;
  }
}

// funtion to use the average of entered grades to determine letter grade that it will return to the user
function letterGrade() {

  if (average>= 90) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " A";
  } else if (average>= 80) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " B";
  } else if (average>= 70) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " C";
  } else if (average>= 60) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " D";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " F";
  }
}

myFunction();
gradeAverage();
letterGrade();
```

```html
<p id="gradeInput">You entered the following grades: </p>
<p id="finalGrade">Your grade average is: </p>
```

Better, pass the var:

```js
// function to read five values from series of prompts stored in array
function getGrades() {
  var grades = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    grades[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Grade: "));
    document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML += grades[i] + "  ";
  }
  return grades;
}

// function to calculate the average of the five entered grades and store it in a variable
function getSum(grades) {
  var totalSum =  0;
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    totalSum += grades[i];
  }
  return totalSum;
}

// funtion to use the average of entered grades to determine letter grade that it will return to the user
function letterGrade(grades) {
  var totalSum = getSum(grades);
  var average = totalSum / grades.length;
  var finalGrade = "";
  if (average >= 90) {
    finalGrade = "A";
  } else if (average >= 80) {
    finalGrade = "B";
  } else if (average >= 70) {
    finalGrade = "C";
  } else if (average >= 60) {
    finalGrade = "D";
  } else {
    finalGrade = "F";
  }
  document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " " + finalGrade;
}

var grades = getGrades()
letterGrade(grades);
```

```html
<p id="gradeInput">You entered the following grades: </p>
<p id="finalGrade">Your grade average is: </p>
```

Comment: it's not working, i get `Your grade average is 43 A` as result

Comment: As result of what numbers?

Comment: @SimonDehaut Haha. Yes. You need to test average and not totalSum! See updates

Answer (score 0):

It is a scope problem. You need to define the variable `average` at the top and not inside the function `gradeAverage`.

```js
var grades = [];
var totalSum = 0;
var average = 0; /* Added */

// function to read five values from series of prompts stored in array
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    grades[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Grade: "));
    document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML += grades[i] + "  ";
  }
}

// function to calculate the average of the five entered grades and store it in a variable
function gradeAverage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    totalSum += grades[i];
    average = totalSum / grades.length;
  }
}

// funtion to use the average of entered grades to determine letter grade that it will return to the user
function letterGrade() {

  if (totalSum <= 90) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " A";
  } else if (totalSum <= 80) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " B";
  } else if (totalSum <= 70) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " C";
  } else if (totalSum <= 60) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " D";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " F";
  }
}

myFunction();
gradeAverage();
letterGrade();
```

```html
<p id="gradeInput">You entered the following grades: </p>
<p id="finalGrade">Your grade average is: </p>
```

Comment: More issues than that

Answer (score 0):

3 issues here:

1. In the 3rd function you use 'average' event though its not defined globally - meaning its not available in the function.
2. It seems you check totalSum <= x even though you probably want to check average <= x.
3. The order of checks in the 3rd function will always result in the first check. Because even if average <= 60 its also <= 90. Reverse the order of checks so the lower grades will be first:

   ```
   if (totalSum <= 50) {
       document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " F";
   } else if(totalSum <= 60) {
       document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " D";
   } else if (totalSum <= 70) {
       document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " C";
   } else if (totalSum <= 80) {
       document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " B";
   } else if (totalSum <= 90) {
       document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " A";
   } else {
       document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " A+";
   }
   ```

Comment: Also DRY - don't repeat yourself

Answer (score 0):

Before giving the solution you need to understand the scopes of variables in javascript.

Consider the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var carName = "Volvo";
    //code here CAN use the variable carName
}

function someAnotherFunction(){
    console.log(carName);
    //code here CANNOT use the variable carName
    //It will the error that carName is not defined.
}
//code here CANNOT use the variable carName
```

Another case:

```
var carName = "Volvo";
function myFunction() {
    console.log(carName);
    //code here CAN use the variable carName
}

function someAnotherFunction(){
    console.log(carName);
    //code here CAN use the variable carName
}
console.log('Check my value here again: '+carName);
//code here CAN also use the variable carName
```

The difference to note here is, The scope/visibility of variable is limited to opening and closing brackets in which it is placed. Outside the closing brackets the very same variable won't be visible outside the brackets, in which it was declared.

Same way you cannot use *average* variable outside the brackets from where it was declared.

Looking at your code few things needs to be changed.

1. Move the average declaration outside the brackets, so that it becomes visible.

```
var average =0;
function gradeAverage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    totalSum += grades[i];
    average = totalSum / grades.length;
  }
}
```

And in the function where grades are calculated, the condition when the average is greater than 90 needs to be added.

```
function letterGrade() {

  if (average >= 90) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " A";
  } else if (average >= 80) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " B";
  } else if (average >= 70) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " C";
  } else if (average >= 60) {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " D";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("finalGrade").innerHTML += average + " F";
  }
}
```

Rest would be fine as it is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @mplungjan one change i got, the usage of avg. variable isn't proper. Which I've changed. Is there anything else which i've missed.

Comment: @mplungjan okay got it. That was the only change right? Thanks for pointing out I missed it in hurry though..